# Is there a way to convert number of Bookmark buttons to Drop down list/slicer in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am using PowerBI for creating visualizations. I have created a page that has 93 different tables that have to be viewed. I created bookmarks but having so many bookmarks in a single page looks very odd, can we create by any chance a dropdown and link it to bookmarks. So that we can view data in a single page and single click.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I would reduce the number of visuals down and sperate them to different pages. Each visual is 1 query so you are doing 92 queries on each page load. Move them into pages and navigate using the bookmarks. You can't list bookmarks in a slicer

Comment: Thanks Jon for your response. I will surely look into this angle